# Dúvida com ng-pattern número de entrada com 2 casas decimais - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou querendo formatar um valor decimal para que sempre seja enviado neste formatado: 00.00, eu tenho um exemplo neste site http://gsferreira.com/archive/2015/02/angularjs-input-number-with-two-decimal-places/

Se digitar 20.10 = 20.1 (queria que ficasse assim 20.10)
se digitar 15.00 = 15 (queria que ficasse assim 15.00)

```
   <input class="form-control input-sm"  type="number" name="myDecimal" placeholder="Decimal" ng-model="numero.valor" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" step="0.01" />
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!--inserindo a meta tag de keywords onde definimos as palavras chaves-->
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <!--descrição do nosso site-->
    <meta name="description" content="Sistema" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--inseri um logo para o meu sistema <!-https://www.iconfinder.com -->
    <link href="../Content/images/logo.png" rel="shortcut icon" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Sistema</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- adicionado o css do carousel -->
    <link href="~/Content/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


    <script>
        angular.module("ListaDados", []);
        angular.module("ListaDados").controller("ListaDadosCtrl", function ($scope) {
            $scope.app = "Dados que serão inseridos";

            $scope.numeros = [];

            $scope.adicionar = function (numero) {
               $scope.numeros.push(angular.copy(numero));
               delete $scope.numero;
            };

            $scope.apagar = function (numeros) {
               $scope.numeros = numeros.filter(function (numero) {
                    if (!numero.selecionado) return numero;
                });
            };


            $scope.isNumeroSelecionado = function (numeros) {
                return numeros.some(function(numero){
                  return numero.selecionado;
                });
            };



        });
    </script>


</head>




<div class="container droppedHover">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-prepend input-append">
            <input class="form-control input-sm " onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);" placeholder="número" maxlength="4"  type="text"  ng-model="numero.nJogo" />
            <input class="form-control input-sm"  type="number" name="myDecimal" placeholder="Decimal" ng-model="numero.valor" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" step="0.01" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block " ng-click="adicionar(numero)" ng-disabled="!numero.nJogo || !numero.valor">Adicionar</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block " ng-click="apagar(numeros)" ng-show="isNumeroSelecionado(numeros)" >Apagar</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a sua pergunta, você quer que quando o valor for passado do model para a view que ele seja exibido com duas casas decimais? E se o usuário decidir editar o campo que contém o valor formato e digitar um com apenas uma casa decimal? O que deve acontecer? Se você puder explicar melhor qual a lógica que você deseja nesse input talvez fique mais fácil pra galera te ajudar.

Comment: eu já tenho uma solução, postei a resposta completa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução mais simples para formatação de casas decimais:

```
<!-- adicionado para formatar em moeda corrente -->
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-locale_pt-br.js"></script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código Completo ficou assim:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!--inserindo a meta tag de keywords onde definimos as palavras chaves-->
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <!--descrição do nosso site-->
    <meta name="description" content="Sistema" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--inseri um logo para o meu sistema <!-https://www.iconfinder.com -->
    <link href="../Content/images/logo.png" rel="shortcut icon" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Sistema</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- adicionado o css do carousel -->
    <link href="~/Content/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- adicionado para formatar em moeda corrente -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-locale_pt-br.js"></script> 
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>



    <script>
        angular.module("ListaDados", []);
        angular.module("ListaDados").controller("ListaDadosCtrl", function ($scope) {
            $scope.app = "Dados que serão inseridos";

            $scope.numeros = [];
            $scope.total = 0;


            $scope.adicionar = function (numero) {
                $scope.numeros.push(angular.copy(numero));
                $scope.total += parseFloat(numero.valor);
                $scope.total = toFixed($scope.total);
                delete $scope.numero; //aqui eu limpo os campos dos inputs apos adicionar
            };

            $scope.apagar = function (numeros) {
                $scope.numeros = numeros.filter(function (numero) {
                    if (!numero.selecionado) return numero;
                });
            };


            $scope.isNumeroSelecionado = function (numeros) {
                return numeros.some(function(numero){
                  return numero.selecionado;
                });
            };

            //função para subtrair os valores
            $scope.subtrairValores = function () {
                $scope.numeros.forEach(function (el, i) {
                    if ($scope.numeros[i].selecionado) { $scope.total -= parseFloat($scope.numeros[i].valor); };
                })
                $scope.total = toFixed($scope.total);
            };


        });
    </script>

    <!-- formatar casas decimais-->
    <script>
        function toFixed(number) {
            number = parseFloat(number);
            if (number % 1 != 0) {
                return parseFloat(number.toFixed(2));
            } else {
                return number;
            }
        }

    </script>



</head>




<br />
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><small> Vendedor: @Session["nome"]</small> </div>
    <div class="panel-heading"><small> Jogo: @Session["descricao_modalidade"] </small></div>
    <div class="panel-heading"><small> Limite: @Session["limite_aceite"] </small></div>
    <div class="panel-heading"><small> Extração: @Session["descricao_estracao"] </small></div>
    <div class="panel-heading"><small> Fechamento: @Session["hora_fechamento"] - Dia: @Session["dia_da_semana"] </small></div>
    <div class="panel-heading"><small> Valor Total Jogo:  {{total  | currency}}  </small></div> <!-- formatar o valor com casas decimais-->
 </div>


<table class="table table-bordered" ng-show="numeros.length > 0" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>X</th>
            <th>Número: </th>
            <th>Valor: </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-class="{'selecionado negrito':numero.selecionado}"  ng-repeat=" numero in numeros" >
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="numero.selecionado" /></td>
            <td>{{numero.nJogo}}</td>
            <td>{{numero.valor | currency }}</td> <!-- formatar o valor com casas decimais-->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


@*<input class="form-control input-sm" onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);" placeholder="valor" maxlength="5" type="text" ng-model="numero.valor" />*@

<div class="container droppedHover">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-prepend input-append">
            <input class="form-control input-sm " onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);" placeholder="número" maxlength="4"  type="text"  ng-model="numero.nJogo" />
            <input class="form-control input-sm"  type="number" name="myDecimal" ng-change="somarValores()"  placeholder="Decimal" ng-model="numero.valor" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block " ng-click="adicionar(numero)" ng-disabled="!numero.nJogo || !numero.valor">Adicionar</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block " ng-click="subtrairValores(); apagar(numeros)" ng-show="isNumeroSelecionado(numeros)" >Apagar</button>

</div>

<br />
```

Answer (score 1):

ng-pattern é usada apenas para validação, além dela você vai precisar criar uma diretiva que requeira ngModel e inclua um $parse para fazer este trabalho.

Em resumo faça algo como:

```
angular.module('seuApp').directive('suaDirective', function() {
  return {
require: 'ngModel',
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
  ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(data) {
    return parseFloat(data).toFixed(2); //converted
  });
}
  }
});
```

Depois só incluir no HTML.

Comment: eu não conseguir fazer o seu exemplo, eu adicionei o código completo na minha pergunta, seria possível você utilizar ele para montar este seu exemplo para que fique mais fácil o entendimento? agradeço

Comment: eu já tenho uma solução, postei a resposta completa. Agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: olá, ainda bem que conseguiu. voltei hoje do feriadão lol